# Problema com Selenium x C# x Chrome

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, integração

Boa tarde. Tenho uma aplicação web feita em c#.
Preciso fazer uma integração via Selenium com outro site e estou tendo os seguinte problemas:

Ao instanciar o webdriver para chrome da erro, abre o navegador mas não segue no código para abrir a página. (no firefox funciona)

> [2144:7568:0519/130434:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the
>   cache: 0 [2144:7568:0519/130434:ERROR:cache_creator.cc(129)] Unable to
>   create cache [2144:7568:0519/130434:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(589)]
>   Shader Cache Creation failed: -2

Outra coisa é quando roda pelo servidor onde foi publicado, nem erro da e nem o browser é aberto, acredito que tenha que enviar algum arquivo para o servidor de aplicação....

Alguém trabalha com selenium e c# e possa dar uma ajuda...
Obrigado
t+

Comment: Adicionando mais informações. Fiz o seguinte teste: Criei 2 projetos um no vs2010 e outro no vs2015. Adicionei as mesmas referências do selenium. No 2010 da erro e no 2015 funciona normalmente.